# How to replace java script parameter in objective-c?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, html, virtual-reality

I was trying to use [Apple HTML5 VR](http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/threesixty/) in my sample project ...

It looks Fine as this [sample code](https://github.com/WebberLai/ThreeSixtyForIPad) .

> threesixty.js

```
threeSixty = {
    init: function() {
        this._vr = new AC.VR('viewer', 'images/optimized/Seq_v04_640x378_##.jpg', 72, {
            invert: true
        });
    },
    didShow: function() {
        this.init();
    },
    willHide: function() {
        recycleObjectValueForKey(this, "_vr");
    },
    shouldCache: function() {
        return false;
    }
}
if (!window.isLoaded) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        threeSixty.init();
    }, false);
}
```

It load Seq_v04_640x378_01.jpg ~ Seq_v04_640x378_72.jpg

But I was curious , if I want add another picture to display 360

How to change picture name ???

Thanks for any reply or answer : )

Webber

/*Edit - Add Projec dictionary screenshot*/
[image]
And there are 72 pics in "optimized" dictionary

Comment: What do you mean by "add another picture"? Add a 73rd pic to the sequence or a completely different sequence? Or a picture with a different name pattern?

Comment: a completely different sequence pictures, apologize for my bad English

Comment: Don't worry, see my answer below. Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you , just check your answer : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** You have to edit `threesixty.js`: inside the `new AC.VR( ... )` function call,  it's enough to replace:

- `images/optimized/Seq_v04_640x378_##.jpg` with the name pattern, and
- `72` with the number of images you have,

as second and third arg, respectively.
Just make sure you placed the files in the right place, that is, a subdirectory of the "threesixty" dir in your project.
If,say, your image sequence files are named:

- frame0001.jpeg
- frame0002.jpeg
- ...
- frame0360.jpeg

Then you'll have to write:

- `images/optimized/frame0###.jpg` as the second arg, and
- `360` as the third arg.

**EDIT** Then, add all your files to the `threesixty/images/optimized/` dir using XCode menu item "Project->Add to project" (CMD+Alt+A).
This way you don't have to rename all your sequence (provided that the files have a name pattern).

Comment: Oh ... I see , just replace the origin sequence pictures with the same name .
That might be help !!!

Comment: You mean there is no way to change any code in new AC.VR() function call.
If so ,your answer is one of solution.
I hope there will exist another one ,a lot pictures copy & replace I think it will waste many time when using mobile device ...

Comment: looks like I can't find the subdirectory path in Xcode simulator :(

Comment: you don't have to rename your pictures, but to change the code. If you have other issues, please edit your question (maybe adding a screenshot of the project tree in XCode would help).

Comment: Thanks ,I upload project screenshot ,by the way ...Is that picture is RX 78-2 ???

Comment: Update my answer... yes it is

Comment: I follow your new answer , the webview become a blank page ???
Only show the <header>

Comment: even if you browse threesixty/index.htm directly using a desktop browser? I think you have to detail a bit more your running enviromnent and maybe post another question. I downloaded your example code from github, just to test it, but the main view controller does _really_ nothing (i.e., there are no error messages). BTW, you don't need an iPad app to test the threesixty stuff, a desktop browser is enough- and when it works you can switch back to an iPad.